# AIR : Data binding nativePath & storageDirectory problem

Tags: air

```
  Encountered errors or warnings while building project 
    project1.mxml: Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "storageDirectory".
    project1.mxml: Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "nativePath".
```

Comment: What ? a few more details might help others understant what this is all about.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest route would be to have a Bindable var on your component and assign these values to it. Though, it probably will detect the changes (storageDirectory won't actually change so it doesn't matter)